# How come this very common sorting method does not sort my list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to sort a list of objects called Sales but the method that everyone seems to use has not been sorting correctly for me. This code below is the class that sorts the list but when I print the "sorted" list in the unit test it shows that it has not been sorted at all.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace ConsoleApplication1 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class modifies an array of all of the sales in order to 
        manipulate the order and contents
    /// which will then print out onto the excel document. 
    /// </summary>
    public class Modifier
    {
        public List<Sales> salesList;

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the constructor for the Modifier object. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sales"> Takes the list of all of the sales objects 
              created. </param>
        public Modifier(List<Sales> list)
        {
            salesList = list;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called by Main to perform all operations within 
            this class. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns> Returns true if exits correctly. </returns>
        public void execute()
        {
            deleteTJ();
            deleteFifteens();

            Console.WriteLine("List contains count: " + 
            salesList.Count.ToString());
            sortMaterial();


        public void sortMaterial() 
        {
            salesList = salesList.OrderBy(o => o.material).ToList();
        }
```

Below this is my test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSort()
{            
    // Add material names to the sales fields created. 
    sale1.material = "DEF123";
    sale2.material = "ABC123";
    sale3.material = "ABC456";
    sale4.material = "GHI123";
    sale5.material = "GHI223";
    sale6.material = "ZZZ999";
    sale7.material = "ABC124";
    sale8.material = "JKL111";
    sale9.material = "ACB123";
    sale10.material = "ABC124";

    // Add sales to the list of sales. 
    testList.Add(sale1);
    testList.Add(sale2);
    testList.Add(sale3);
    testList.Add(sale4);
    testList.Add(sale5);
    testList.Add(sale6);
    testList.Add(sale7);
    testList.Add(sale8);
    testList.Add(sale9);
    testList.Add(sale10);

    // Declare Modifier Object.
    Modifier modifier = new Modifier(testList);

    // Sort sales 1-10 by alphabetical order. 
    modifier.sortMaterial();

    // Print statements to view whole list in output screen
    Console.WriteLine(testList[0].material.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(testList[1].material.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(testList[2].material.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(testList[3].material.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(testList[4].material.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(testList[5].material.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(testList[6].material.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(testList[7].material.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(testList[8].material.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(testList[9].material.ToString());


    Assert.AreEqual("ABC123", testList[0].material);
    Assert.AreEqual("ABC124", testList[1].material);
    Assert.AreEqual("ABC124", testList[2].material);
    Assert.AreEqual("ZZZ999", testList[9].material);
}
```

Comment: What should that code do?

Comment: @PatrickHofman It should sort sales by alphabetical order

Comment: And `salesList.OrderBy(s => s.material)` is not allowed?

Comment: @PatrickHofman When I tried using that it did not sort my list at all. I did not have an error but all of my tests would not pass and after printing out the order I saw nothing changed. I figured that my best bet would be to go back to this method since it mostly worked.

Comment: Have you tried `salesList = salesList.OrderBy(s => s.material)`?

Comment: @maccettura I have done this. I was looking through other stack overflow questions trying to figure out why that much simpler method of sorting did not work and I could not find the answer.

Comment: Note that my comment assigns the value returned from `OrderBy()`, you are telling me that your code did not work, even after **assigning the value returned by OrderBy()**?

Comment: @AlexBochel - maccettura's suggestion should work. OrderBy() is pretty standard and it works :)

Comment: Just to address the scope issue mentioned in the question, swap will change if the code gets into the if statement.  It will however be reset the next time through the outer for loop.

Comment: @AlexBochel Check this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YhYrrs) out, it illustrates what I am talking about.

Comment: @maccettura Yes I did that which is why I am so confused. I did not do anything different

Comment: Can you post the scope of the code where you tried the "sorting".  I would hate for you to have to reinvent the sorting "wheel".

Comment: @maccettura I edited the question to include everything. Thanks! Let me know if you want the MCVE

Comment: I don't see what you do with the list after its sorted.  Also, why not just sort it in the constructor?  In addition, since the nature of your question is changing it might make sense to edit your post to ask why your sort is not working (instead of your earlier scope question).

Comment: There is neither a variable called `swap` nor a `for` loop in the code you posted. I can see that these _were_ in the original question, but now that you've replaced all the code with something completely different, the description of your problem has nothing to do with the code you are showing us.

Comment: @JLRishe I was in the process of editing the question and am doing so now. Sorry it was not updated when you saw the question.

Comment: @maccettura I do not do anything to the list after sorting it. I simply call the sort in the unit test case and nothing is sorted. And thank you for the heads up!

Comment: Ok I see your problem.  You are checking `testList` to see if its sorted, your `sortMaterial()` method sorts the `salesList` member of the `Modifier` class.  If you check `modifier.salesList` that will be sorted.  Or do `testList = modifier.salesList;` after you sort and keep checking testList.

Comment: @maccettura wow thank you so much! I really appreciate your patience and your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't seem to understand how references work in C#. This doesn't have anything to do with scope.

Reference types are a type of placeholder that point to an actual bunch of data off in some other place.

So you start of with your `testList` variable, and that points to a List object somewhere:

```
testList ----->   [List]
```

Then you pass that into the constructor of Modifier, and the Modifier has a field called `salesList`, to which it assigns the passed in reference. Now `testList` and `salesList` are referencing the same list:

```
testList ----->  [List]
                ^
    salesList  /
```

Then you call `sortMaterial()`, which uses `OrderBy`. `OrderBy` leaves the original list unmodified and returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, from which you create a *new list*, which you assign to `salesList`, so now `testList` and `salesList` refer to *different* lists:

```
 testList ----> [original list]

 salesList ----> [sorted list]
```

Up to this point, the original list remains untouched and that is why you are seeing the results you are seeing.

You could get the code to work the way you want by [sorting the list in-place](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of using an approach that leaves the original list untouched. But nowadays, people tend to avoid modifying objects when they don't have to. So what I would advise would be to change `sortMaterial` so that it returns the sorted list:

```
public List<Sales> sortMaterial() 
{
     salesList = salesList.OrderBy(o => o.material).ToList();

     return salesList;
}
```

Then you can assign that result to your `testList` variable when you call it:

```
testList = modifier.sortMaterial();
```

and your code should not work like you're expecting.